# Oracle 10.2.0.5 - SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a strange Oracle query problem. Trouble is I'm an MS SQL developer really.

It's a fair chunk of SQL, but when it ends with this:

```
WHERE     RLTEST.D550M.PERSON_REF = '00027280';
```

all works fine.

When it ends in this:

```
WHERE     RLTEST.D550M.PERSON_REF = '00027280'
AND       RLTEST.D580M.PROJECTED_END_DATE <= SYSDATE();
```

I get `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

and when it ends in this:

```
WHERE     RLTEST.D550M.PERSON_REF = '00027280'
AND       NVL(RLTEST.D580M.PROJECTED_END_DATE, SYSDATE()-1) <= SYSDATE();
```

I get `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

What do I need to do to add the date comparison?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the extra brackets - remove the "()" from just after sysdate.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a concept of pseudocolumns and sysdate is one of them, so you should remove the brackets/braces immediately after you reference it.

More info on pseudocolumns is available [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Pseudo-column)